# making a range for data points in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, double, range

If a user enters a value for
 `x y` and `z` coordinates, what steps would  need to take in order to create a range from `-x/y/z` to `+x/y/z?` Is there a function that will give the numbers in that range even though a double is entered?

This is my code so far im not finished yet, I'm not sure if its right. After it gets the  x,y,z points and the number of data points the user wants, it will then print the n number of points with random points (x , y, z) x, y, z being anywhere from -x to x etc.

```
    import java.io.*;

public class MultiDimArray
{

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));// Buffered Reader reads the number inputed
double range;

System.out.println("How many points do you want returned? ");
String numPointsA = myInput.readLine();
int numPoints = Integer.parseInt(numPointsA);

System.out.println("Enter X length: ");
String xlengthA = myInput.readLine();
double xlength = Double.parseDouble(xlengthA);

System.out.println("Enter Y length: ");
String ylengthA = myInput.readLine();
double ylength = Double.parseDouble(ylengthA);


System.out.println("Enter Z length: ");
String zlengthA = myInput.readLine();
double zlength = Double.parseDouble(zlengthA);


int[][][][]  dataPoint  =  new int[3][xlength][ylength][zlength];

for (int i = 0; i < (xlength * 2); i++){
 range = (0 -( xlength - i) + 1);
 System.out.println(range);
 }
for (int i = 0; i < (ylength * 2); i++){
 range = (0 -( ylength - i) + 1);
 }
for (int i = 0; i < (zlength * 2); i++){
 range = (0 -( zlength - i) + 1);
 }


}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What does the `+` mean in there?

Comment: There are an infinite amount of numbers in any range.

Comment: The concept of "range" doesn't exist the way you appear to think it does.  Consider the point in space at coordinates `(x, y, z)`, and the point diametrically "opposite" (through the origin) at `(-x,-y,-z)`.  You could be talking about a cube of points  centered at the origin with those two points being opposite corners... or it could be a sphere... or any other shape.  You have to define what you mean by "range".  And then you have to decide what resolution you need -- i.e. the increment in each dimension between any two points in the "range".

Comment: sorry, didnt mean to add the +. My program is supposed to get one random x y and z points from a multi dimensional array. The range of each row in the array is from whatever the user enters (1st row- -x to x, 2nd row- -y to y...) I just not sure on how to get the array from -x/y/z to x/y/z.

Comment: Please show some code with the arrays you have to search and indicate why you think you need a negative index value.

Comment: i've posted my code so far at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

range is infinite if you want to include all fractional numbers otherwise you can do that manually.

for (int i=-x; i<=x; i++)
       operate(i, y, z);

another solution for your problem is that you don't generate range.

you just store those values x y and z.

then, when you need to test if a number is in range you can do it easily with if statement.

what I mean that this a wrong way to design your solution. try to get values you want in another way. something like reverse engineering. then you test if those values are in range.

post your problem. then we can help you.

---

Code that generates numPointsA random numbers between -x and x:

```
Random random = new Random();
double start = -x;
double end = x;
for (int i=0;i<numPointsA;i++)
{
    double ran = random.nextDouble();
    double result = start + (ran * (end - start));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a random number between 0 and n-1, use

```
Random rand = new Random();
int r = rand.nextInt(n);
```